# How to write the correct recipe for an HTTP POST request on Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to write a recipe for an HTTP POST request in **Groovy** and the way I am doing it is by editing a previous recipe but adjusting it to my own needs:

1. Set two request properties (Content-Type: application/json, Authorization: Bearer xxxxx)
2. Set raw data (json) ({"var_1": "value 1", "var_2": "value 2"})

The recipe I'm trying to modify is

```
def baseUrl = new URL('http://some.url.com/')
def connection = baseUrl.openConnection()
connection.with {
    doOutput = true
    requestMethod = 'POST'
    setRequestProperty = ['Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxx']
    outputStream.withWriter { writer ->
    writer
    }
    println content.text
}
```

At first when executing the script I get the following error:

```
Exception thrown

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://some.url.com/
```

The other thing is that I don't know how to add the need (2) to the script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Javadoc I would put the code like so:

```
def baseUrl = new URL('http://some.url.com/')

def connection = baseUrl.openConnection()
connection.with {
    doOutput = true
    requestMethod = 'POST'
    addRequestProperty 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
    addRequestProperty 'Authorization', 'Bearer xxxx'
    outputStream.withWriter{ it << '{"var_1": "value 1", "var_2": "value 2"}' }
    println content.text
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, u save my day!